# Prove boundedness in the polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

> Prove *using first principles*: $42n^8 + 16n^5 + 5n\log(n) + 2017 \in O(n^{10})$

I am not sure where to begin and what "first principles" exactly means?

Comment: A good place to start is the definition of Big $O$ notation. See the formal definition here: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Big_O_notation.

The formal definition describes what it means for something to be a member of $O(n^{10})$. To prove $42n^8+16n^5+5nlog(n)+2017 \in O(n^{10})$ by first principles, you show that the expression on the left satisfies conditions listed in the formal definition.

Comment: You might start by noting that $\forall n \in \mathbf{N}$ $(42+16+5+2017)|n^{10}|=(42+16+5+2017)n^{10}= 42n^{10}+16n^{10}+5n^{10}+2017n^{10} \geq \cdots$

Comment: Using the Wiki page as an example $M=(42+16+5+2017)=2080$ in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Proving this is not difficult, once you understand intuitively why the statement holds. In general, you have $n^m \in O(n^k)$ for $k \geq m$ (note that you only need to bound the first term by a multiple of the second for all $n > n_0$ for some suitable $n_0$, in this case e.g. $n_0 = 1$; assuming that n is supposed to be an integer, which was not explicitly mentioned above, this doesn't matter, but it would be important if we wanted to prove the asymptotics on R). Furthermore, it is immediately clear that for $f(n), g(n) \in O(h(n))$ you have $f(n)+g(n) \in O(h(n))$ (by adding the constants) and $\lambda f(n) \in O(h(n))$ (by scaling the constant).

Therefore, the term to worry about is the logarithmic term. Proving that $n \log n \in O(n^{10})$ means to find an $n_0$ and a $\lambda$ such that, for $n > n_0$, $n \log n$ is bounded by $\lambda n^{10}$, or equivalently, $$\log n \leq \lambda n^{9}$$
Now imagine the graph of the logarithm function: It is very flat towards $+\infty$, whereas $n^9$ is very steep. I don't know if it can be considered a first principle that $\log n \in O(n^\alpha)\,\forall \alpha 
> 0$. It can be seen e.g. by noting $$\forall x > 1: \log x = \int_1^x \frac{dt}{t} < \int_1^x \frac{dt}{t^{1-\alpha}} = \frac 1 \alpha ( x^{\alpha} - 1)$$

Answer (score 0):

> $$\lim_{n \rightarrow 0}\frac{ 42n^8 + 16n^5 + 5n\log(n) + 2017}{n^{10}}=0$$

Thus for $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that  $42n^8 + 16n^5 + 5n\log(n) + 2017 <\frac{1}{2}n^{10} \leq Cn^{10}$ forall  $n \geq n_0$ and for some $C\geq\frac{1}{2}$ forall  $n \geq n_0$

Thus  $42n^8 + 16n^5 + 5n\log(n) + 2017 \in O(n^{10})$